# What do these lines mean (Scala / JavaTokenParsers)?

Tags: scala, parsing

I am trying to better understand how to do mass parsing/interpreting.

I am having difficulty understanding lines like these:

```
type L = () => Long
```

And then later there are other lines like

```
val term = chainl1(myNum, "[*/]".r ^^ {
  case "*" => (u1:L, u2:L) => () => u1() * u2()
  case "/" => (u1:L, u2:L) => () => u1() / u2()
})
```

I am just trying to understand the underlying structure here. What exactly is `()` here? What is the logical flow of these `val` statements?

I assume this means "if we find `*` or `/` in `myNum`, match on these two cases depending on which one it is, and then... long flow of logic I don't understand"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer of ka4ell is correct, but does not mention why you would use `() => Long` instead of just using `Long`: with `() => Long` or `L` the execution of the calculation which returns the `Long` is delayed. We only execute the functions at the moment we want the actual result, this is called **lazy** evaluation.

In your case:

```
case "*" => 
  // Return a function which takes two Ls : u1 and u2
  // and which returns an L : () => u1() * u2()
  (u1:L, u2:L) => () => u1() * u2()
```

Let's define a simple function which returns an `L` :

```
// return a function which will return a Long
// this could potentially be a very expensive calculation
def giveMeAnL(n: Long) = () => {
  println("giveMeAnL is called")
  n
}
```

If we would use an analogous function than the one in the case:

```
// analogous case "*" => ...
def multiply(u1:L, u2:L) = () => {
  println("multiply is called")
  u1() * u2()
}

// create two Ls
val (l1, l2) = (giveMeAnL(5L), giveMeAnL(2L))

val productL = multiply(l1, l2) // productL is of type L
```

The value `productL` now contains an `L` which can calculate the product of the two values. At this point, neither the product nor the two values are calculated. If we call the `productL` value, the two values are calculated and the product of these values is calculated.

```
val product = productL()
// multiply is called
// giveMeAnL is called
// giveMeAnL is called
// product: Long = 10
```

If somewhere in your parsing steps, you want to ignore some `L` values, the results of these `L`s are never calculated, which improves the performance.

```
case "multiply first with 5" => 
  (u1:L, u2:L) => () => u1() * 5L // u2 is never executed
```

Comment: I tried replacing L with some other arbitrary letter like X to see if this was a general thing, and it gave me errors. Does this whole thing only work with Long? Is L somehow shorthand for some native type? It also seemed to execute when I removed the L's from the 5 and 2. I'm still struggling to understand what the heck type L = () => Long is doing and why we'd want it

Comment: I just used the type `L`, since that was what you were using, it is no native type.

Comment: Try replacing L with another letter like X, and it suddenly stops working: val productX = multiply(giveMeAnX(5X), giveMeAnX(2X)) //Invalid literal number

Comment: The `L` after `5L` and `2L` is an unlucky consequence. It works without the `L` because the `5` and `2` `Int`s here are turned  into `Longs`

Comment: So adding an L after a number IS something native to Scala and unrelated to this question? It's typecasting it to Long, but this is unnecessary because this is done automatically in the call to giveMeAnX due to the argument type "(n: Long)"?

Comment: Adding the `L`  of `l` after a number to make it an explicit `Long` is unrelated to this question yes, in Java you can do the samething. In Scala an `Int` will be automatically converted to a `Long` when a `Long` is expected yes.

Comment: It might have been clearer if I had replaced the type alias `L`  with `type DelayedLong = () => Long`, but I wanted to stay close to your code.

Comment: So "def giveMeAnL(n: Long) = () =>" implies that if we do "l1 = giveMeAnL(5)" we're only storing a function in l1 with an argument 5. So if we do l1() then we actually excute the body of giveMeAnL with argument 5. The "type" of l1 is therefore () => Long (a function returning a Long), which is why we use L to represent this? I could technically then replace L with "() => Long" everywhere, including the function body of multiply()?

Comment: What if we just wanted to make giveMeAnL a function accepting one argument? Like one where it doesn't have 5 "stored" inside it, but rather something where later we can do l1(5) and have it invoke giveMeAnL(5)? Would this be giveMeAnL(n:Long) = (Long) => { n } and then later l1 would be of type "(Long) => Long"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. If you want to take a parameter you can write a function like `multiply`, eg `def squared(u1: L) = () => u1() * u1()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
type L = () => Long
```

describes a function with zero arguments and return type Long. For example

```
def someConstant() = 5L
```

Here `someConstant` is of type `L`.

This line

```
case "*" => (u1:L, u2:L) => () => u1() * u2()
```

will return you a function of type `Function2` (arity 2) with return  type `Function0`(arity 0) which when is called will return the result of `u1() * u2()`.

---

`val f = () => (x:Int) => x`

can be written as

`() => ((x: Int) => x)`

Here f is a function with arity 0 which when is called returns another function with arity 1 which accepts Int argument and returns it when called.

```
 f()(6) == 6
```

is true statement.

Comment: So what is a line like "case "*" => (u1:L, u2:L) => () => u1() * u2()" saying?

Comment: I'm still not quite sure I understand. It says "case *" and then somehow extracts two numbers -- is it saying that u1 and u2 must be of type L, or are they being "cast" to L? And then why the extra => () => part? Why the u1() and u2()?

Comment: scala is not that language you can learn by looking through code examples, if you are doing that. You need to read a book, go though tutorials etc. It often has much more complex structures than this, and you will be lost there if you won't prepare yourself

Comment: @Archeg I learn best through example. Reading abstract tutorials and books has never helped me. I need hard examples to understand how things are being put together. I can figure out the abstraction after the fact.

Comment: @user5127720 just look at the code example in the answer here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261082/scala-macro-to-print-code and decide for yourself whether you can learn scala by example. If you still want to do that, I wish you luck :)

Comment: Showing some complex code (where even comments in the thread mention how unreadable they are) that is well above the complexity of this particular code question is not a strong example, I would say. I'm not interested in getting into a debate, though -- I just want to understand this example for now.

Comment: It doesn't extract two numbers. In case of "*" it returns a function that accepts two arguments of type L. This function needs to be called to do anything, and you need to pass two values of type L, which is itself functions. So this case returns a function that accepts two functions and provides a result of type Long.

Comment: What is each piece doing though, I mean? I understand the overall gist but not the pieces. "=> (u1:L, u2:L)" versus  "=> ()" versus  "=> u1() * u2()"

Answer (score 0):

If we split the line `case "*" => (u1:L, u2:L) => () => u1() * u2()`:

`case "*" =>` means match `*` to the code that is written next

`(u1:L, u2:L) => {}` is a definition of function that has two arguments of type `L`

`u1` and `u2` are functions, because their type is `L`, and it is actually `() => Long` which means this is a function that takes nothing and returns `Long`

`() => u1() * u2()` is a function with no arguments, that calls `u1` and `u2` and multiplies their results
Going back:
`(u1:L, u2:L) => () => u1() * u2()` is a function of two arguments which returns a function of no arguments, that executes both arguments of a first function, multiplies them and return the result

So, `() =>` means a function with no arguments. The only exception here is `case * =>` where `=>` doesn't belong to a function, but rather to match statement

Comment: I guess the main hiccup for me is this idea of a function "accepting no arguments" suddenly branching into something that seems to accept arguments. For instance I don't understand how we go from () to u1() and u2(). Aren't u1 and u2 "arguments"? Something just seems needlessly complicated here. We've got a function definition of two functions returning a no-argument function returning a multiplier of two functions that correspond to a type that return no-argument functions yielding longs? What?

Comment: `u1` and `u2` are the arguments of the parent function. The child function just has closure around them. Small example, assuming `L = Int`. Let's say you have `val parentF = (u1:L, u2:L) => () => u1 * u2`. Then you take `val childF = parentF(2, 3)`. `childF` is still a function, but it has no arguments. And now it looks kinda like `() => 2 * 3` (it's not precise, but I think it helps to understand it). What happens here is that `childFunction` when it was created, remembered the references to `u1` and to `u2`, and this behavior is called closure. Just remember that `L = () => Long` in reality

Comment: So childFunction is a function accepting no arguments because the arguments were already encapsulated in parentF when we made the assignment? Now any time we deal with childF we are implicitly dealing with parentF(2,3) specifically?

Comment: In other words childF references parentF(2,3), and having two arguments 2,3 here is fine because parentF is a function of form (u1:Int, u2:Int), which returns a function, which, when invoked, will multiply u1 and u2. So now if I output childF(), it will output 6? Am I understanding the flow right?

Comment: childFunction is a function accepting no arguments because it is defines with `() => ...` But it actually requires `u1` and `u2` and cannot work without them. It is called closure, because a function that requires `u1` and `u2`, but does not have them is called `opened` (if I correctly mention the term). So it is closed by having a parent function which has `u1` and `u2`. And I still recommend you to start reading a book :) Just look at the size of the discussion you've triggered

Comment: Alright, I'll concede the point on this one. Do you have any books you'd recommend?

Comment: @user5127720 yes, you do understand it correctly. But remember that my example was about L = Int, and you have L = () => Long, so you need to count that

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/books.html I think that the first one (by Martin) is great, and he is the Scala's author I think (It's also free if you read it online). But I have read only his book, so no opinion on the others. P.S. his book is also built around code examples, so it might fit your learning style

Comment: Well if you understand all this stuff and that's the only book you've read on the subject, either it's a damn good book, or you're a genius (or both). I'll give it a shot. Thanks!